# mysql query returning null when not should to

Tags: php

I use this PHP code to get value from my DB.

My problem is that i got null result.

I check for !empty($result) and for mysql_num_rows($result) but still i got null result.

I tested **exactly** the same query i use in my code on my phpmyadmin and it working.

The echo from `$response["SQL"]` is "good".

Here is my PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM workouts_wall WHERE workout_name = 'WO13' AND user = 'tomer2'") or die (mysql_error());


// mysql inserting a new row
 if (!empty($result))
 {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        $response["SQL"] = "good";
    }
    else
    {
        $response["SQL"] = "bad";
    }
}

else    
{
    $response["SQL"] = "bad";
}   


$response["is null?"] = $result;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
```

---

**Solved**

I added this line to fix it:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Have you checked for any errors?  `mysql_error()` may shed some light on your issue.

Comment: mysql_error() doesnt show any errors.

Comment: Ha, yeah I just saw the `or die` section at the end...

Comment: Have you connected to the db? BTW, you should be using either `mysqli` or `PDO` - the `mysql` functions are not secure.

Comment: I think that im connected i dont get any error from my mysql_query.

Thanks for the advice about mysqli and PDO.

Comment: @adam It's not that the `mysql_*()` functions are necessarily insecure (if implemented correctly), it's that they're deprecated.  Bad idea to write code using functions that won't be there in the future.

Comment: how come `$response["SQL"]` is `"good"` if you are getting `null`?

Comment: You are not checking the error you may be getting from the query. Try adding `mysql_error()` output into the `else` block of code when `$result` is being checked.

Comment: @akonsu i dont know how it is possible. Thats what my echo said.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just return the `mysql_query` results.  You must fetch the data.

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    $data[] = $row;

echo(json_encode($data));

//EDIT: Also a good idea when you are done...
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: when i try to get values from my result i gets null.
If i do `$result["workout_name"]` and echo it i get null value

Comment: You can't do `$result["workout_name"]`, you need to fetch the row from your data first, and then do something like `echo $row["workout_name"]`

Comment: I tried `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) $response["check"] = $row["workout_name"];` and i still got null for my echo

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_query()` function returns either a resource or a boolean.  If your query is successful (as it probably is in this case), you're still only assigning the MySQL resource to your `$response` variable.  You need to actually use something like [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) or [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) to extract the returned data.

Regarding not using the `mysql_*()` functions: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

try this. hope it work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM workouts_wall WHERE workout_name = 'WO13' AND user = 'tomer2'") or die (mysql_error());


    // mysql inserting a new row
     if (!empty(mysql_fetch_array($result)))
     {
        if (mysql_num_rows(($result) > 0) 
        {
            $response["SQL"] = "good";
        }
        else
        {
              $response["SQL"] = "bad";
        }
    }

    else    
    {
        $response["SQL"] = "bad";
    }   


    $response["is null?"] = $result;
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

A mysql result which has no rows is **NOT** empty. It's a standard mysql result handle which simply happens to actually contain no rows. It's not an error, it's not an empty string, it's not an empty array... it's a standard result handle, like any other result handle.

Your code should be

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); // catch the REAL errors
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { 
   ... result set is empty
}
```

Comment: Sorry, brainfart on my part. Should've been mysql_num_rows, not count.